# Creating a table for frequency analysis results in R

Tags: r, dplyr, crosstab, tabular

I need to create a table of a certain type and based on a certain template.

This is my data:

```
df = structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L),
                    degree = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L),
                                       .Label = c("Mild severity", "Moderate severity", "Severe severity"),
                                       class = "factor")), 
               .Names = c("group", "degree"), 
               class = "data.frame", 
               row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I conducted a crosstab:

```
table(df$degree,df$group)
                   
                    1 2 3
  Mild severity     3 3 2
  Moderate severity 0 0 1
  Severe severity   0 0 1
```

but I need the results to be formatted in this template:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How can I create a table with this structure?

## very important edit

full dput() (42 obs.)

```
df = structure(list(Study.Subject.ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 8L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L),
                                                 .Label = c("01-06-104", "01-09-108", "01-15-201", "01-16-202", "01-18-204", "01-27-301", "01-28-302", "01-33-305", "01-42-310"),
                                                 class = "factor"),
                    group = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                    Degree.of.severity = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L),
                                                   .Label = c("Life-threatening or disabling", "Mild severity", "Moderate severity", "Severe severity"),
                                                   class = "factor")),
              .Names = c("Study.Subject.ID", "group", "Degree.of.severity"),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c(NA, -42L))
```

There is a concept of the subject, and there is concept a number of side effects.
One person can have several side effects.
The side effect can be

```
severity
Moderate
Severe
```

I have to count how many people separated by group have this or that side effect,
and how many side effects are in this group?

I.E. In the first group we have 9 observations, but there are two unique people.

```
01-06-104
01-09-108
```

but total count `Mild severity` is 7.
So only two people have side effects of `Mild severity` (X) and total count `Mild severity` is 7 (Y).
Total count of patients is 42, so to calculate percentage we must divide by 42 (2/42)=4,7

That's why I expected the output to be:

```
    degree       group1           group2         group3 
                  X (%)Y          X (%)Y         X (%) Y
                        
    Mild severity   2 (4,7%)7   3 (7,1%)13   3(7,1%)    12
    Moderato        1 (2,3%)1   0(0,0%%)0    2(4,7%)    6
    Severe severity 0(0,0%%)0   0(0,0%%)0     1(2,3)    1
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're after. Are you asking how how to generate a frequency (instead of a count) table? Or how to layout a table both with counts and frequencies? Or how to to store the output of a table in Excel? I don't understand what columns `X` and `Y` are supposed to denote. Can you add your expected output based on the sample data (not as an image but with real data)?

Comment: @MauritsEvers i edited post, please check it, Your answer is right, but need addtion.

Comment: The edited dput is not enough to give you the results that you want

Comment: @Onyambu, and MauritsEvers   i updated dput  with more obs.

Comment: The edited `dput` still does not help. All `Study.Subject.ID`s are different, so I don't understand what you mean by *"So it is not three men, it is one person has 3 side effects"*. You need to take a step back, come up with a **representative & minimal** sample dataset, and clearly present your expected output **based on the sample data**. Your expected output should contain the full table with actual numbers, not just a (part of a) screenshot. Only then will it be possible to provide help.

Comment: @MauritsEvers, i edited post with detail explanation and desired output,please check.

Answer (score 3):

I have to admit that I'm not clear on what you're trying to do. Unfortunately your expected output image does not help.

I *assume* you are asking how to calculate a 2-way contingency table and show both counts and percentages (of total). Here is a `tidyverse` possibility

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    group_by(group, degree) %>%
    summarise(n = n(), perc = n() / nrow(.)) %>%
    mutate(entry = sprintf("%i (%3.2f%%)", n, perc * 100)) %>%
    select(-n, -perc) %>%
    spread(group, entry, fill = "0 (0.0%%)")
## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  degree            `1`        `2`        `3`
#  <fct>             <chr>      <chr>      <chr>
#1 Mild severity     3 (30.00%) 3 (30.00%) 2 (20.00%)
#2 Moderate severity 0 (0.0%%)  0 (0.0%%)  1 (10.00%)
#3 Severe severity   0 (0.0%%)  0 (0.0%%)  1 (10.00%)
```

Comment: Yes, Very Well ,You right understand what i want, but could you add the new column. I edited post, please check edit

Answer (score 1):

you want the fractions, together with the total numbers? Try:

```r
n=table(df$degree,df$group)
df=as.data.frame(cbind(n/colSums(n)*100,n))
```

Comment: this is a bit wrong,i need to fill according in the table template. provide your output please.  it is different from the table

Answer (score 0):

using base R:

```
a = transform(data.frame(table(df)),Freq = sprintf("%d (%3.2f%%)",Freq,prop.table(Freq)*100))
data.frame(t(unstack(a,Freq~degree)))
                          X1         X2         X3
Mild.severity     3 (30.00%) 3 (30.00%) 2 (20.00%)
Moderate.severity  0 (0.00%)  0 (0.00%) 1 (10.00%)
Severe.severity    0 (0.00%)  0 (0.00%) 1 (10.00%)
```