# multi-group by with count and percentages

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Let's assume I have this df:

```
> df <- data.frame(letter = sample(letters[1:4], 15, replace=TRUE),
+                  time = c("one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "two", "two", "two", "one","one","one","two","one","two"),
+                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df
   letter time
1       d  one
2       a  one
3       a  one
4       b  two
5       c  two
6       a  one
7       d  two
8       a  two
9       b  two
10      b  one
11      d  one
12      b  one
13      c  two
14      a  one
15      a  two
```

Where I'm looking to group them by `Value` and creating a column of `time_one` and another column named `time_two` with their respective counts by `Value`, plus their respective percentages. This is my starting point:

```
> x <- df %>%
+ mutate(Value = letter,
+       n = n()) %>%
+ group_by(Value) %>%
+ summarise(Quantity = length(Value),
+          Percentage = first(length(Value)/n))
> x
  Value Quantity  Percentage
1 a            6           0.4  
2 b            4           0.267
3 c            2           0.133
4 d            3           0.2
```

As you can see above, I have the count for each `Value`, but I need that each `Quantity` from each `Value` to be separated by `one` and `two` values from the time column. So, I will end with something like this:

```
  Value time_one  Percentage   time_two    Percentage
1 a            5  0.5          1           0.2     
2 b            2  0.2          2           0.4    
3 c            1  0.1          1           0.2       
4 d            2  0.2          1           0.2
```

**PS**: I have checked [two by two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51956872/two-by-two-table-with-count-and-percentage-in-r) table and [creating a table for frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187293/creating-a-table-for-frequency-analysis-results-in-r) answers, and they are close to the answer I'm looking, but as I still don't understand very well the `%>%`, `group_by`, `mutate`,`summarise` combinations, it has been a kind of very steep learning curve to use them to separate the count and the percentage of those solutions to get the one I need.

Comment: What is `Valor`?

Comment: I think its just a typo for Value, will onsider this to understand the scope of the question

Comment: My mistake! It's just the spanish translation of "Value". I already corrected it.

Comment: you need to use `set.seed()` before generating random data for reproducbility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tidyverse` you can try:

```
df %>%
 group_by(time) %>%
 mutate(n_time = n()) %>%
 group_by(time, letter) %>%
 summarise(n = n(),
           percentage = first(n()/n_time)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 gather(var, val, -c(time, letter)) %>%
 mutate(var = paste(var, time, sep = "_")) %>%
 select(-time) %>%
 spread(var, val) 

  letter n_one n_two percentage_one percentage_two
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
1 a         3.    2.          0.375          0.286
2 b         2.   NA           0.250         NA    
3 c         2.    2.          0.250          0.286
4 d         1.    3.          0.125          0.429
```

Here it, first, calculates the count per "time". Second, it calculates the count per "time" and "letter" and the proportion of a given letter from the overall count per given time. Third, it transforms the data from wide to long format and creates new variable names that indicates the time. Finally, it returns the data to the desired format.

Comment: It works! But can you explain what it does a little bit? Or maybe just a comment per line of code in order to learn and know what is happening in each line?

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I don't use the modern tidy R but here is a solution in base R if that is acceptable for your needs.

```
df <- data.frame(letter = sample(letters[1:4], 15, replace=TRUE),
                 time = c("one", "one", "one", "two", "two", "one", "two", "two", "two", "one","one","one","two","one","two"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# make sure your letter is a factor with all levels otherwise the subsequent cbind doesn#t work
df$letter = factor(df$letter, levels=letters[1:4])

# get the counts 
x = sapply(split(df$letter, df$time), table)

# get the percentages and cbind together 
x2 = cbind(x, apply(x, 2, function(x) x/sum(x)))

colnames(x2) = c("time_one", "time_two", "percent_one", "percent_two")


  time_one time_two percent_one percent_two
a        0        1         0.0   0.1428571
b        4        4         0.5   0.5714286
c        0        1         0.0   0.1428571
d        4        1         0.5   0.1428571
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
setDT(df)

df[, .N, by = .(letter, time)
   ][, .(N, percentage = N/sum(N), letter), by = time] %>% 
  dcast(letter ~ time, value.var = c("N", "percentage"), fill = 0)

   letter N_one N_two percentage_one percentage_two
1:      a     4     2           0.50      0.2857143
2:      b     2     2           0.25      0.2857143
3:      c     0     2           0.00      0.2857143
4:      d     2     1           0.25      0.1428571
```

*data*

```
df <- structure(list(letter = c("d", "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "d", 
"a", "b", "b", "d", "b", "c", "a", "a"), time = c("one", "one", 
"one", "two", "two", "one", "two", "two", "two", "one", "one", 
"one", "two", "one", "two")), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```